# Best way to combine multiple TBytes arrays

Tags: delphi, arrays, delphi-xe2

What is the best way to combine `TBytes` arrays?

All arrays are of the same size. I want the content of `Array2` to be added to the end of `Array1`, `Array3` to the end of `Array2`, and so forth.

Comment: Define "merge". Do you mean appending one to the end of the other, or intermingling (array1[0], array2[0], array1[1], array2[1])? Are they the same size? Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do, so that we can try and help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: all arrays are of same size and i want like this array1 append array2 append array3 .....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To merge two `TBytes` together, you have to allocate a third `TBytes` that is the total length of the two individual `TBytes`, then copy the bytes from both into it.  For example:

```
var
  arr1, arr2, merged: TBytes;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(merged, Length(arr1) + Length(arr2));
  if arr1 <> nil then Move(arr1[0], merged[0], Length(arr1));
  if arr2 <> nil then Move(arr2[0], merged[Length(arr1)], Length(arr2));
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, which was specifically how to do it `looping through them`.

Comment: I read the question as asking how to loop through a list of arrays, not how to loop through the contents of a particular array.

Comment: I'm not sure how it could. "How to **merge TBytes Array through looping through them**." - what part of "merge ... through looping through them" says "loop through a list of arrays"? If the question is "how do I fix the fuel injection on my Ferrari", the answer isn't "buy a hybrid instead - they're better for the environment" (although that might be a valid (and possibly better) *alternative* to offer after answering the original question). :)

Comment: "through them" is a little ambiquious. It could mean "through a collection of them" or it could mean "through the contents of them". I think Vinamra needs to clearify the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string-like operations:

```
var
  LArray1, LArray2, LMerged: TBytes;
begin
  ...
  LMerged := LArray1 + LArray2;
end;
```

Or you can use the system "Concat" function:

```
var
  LArray1, LArray2, LMerged: TBytes;
begin
  ...
  LMerged := Concat(LArray1, LArray2);
end;
```

Comment: Not with XE2 which is what the question is tagged.